# How to make a synchronous call with WebClient using Open API Code Generator

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-webclient, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Spring in RestTemplate documentation has note:

As of 5.0 the class  org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate is in maintenance mode, with only minor requests for changes and bugs to be accepted going forward. Please, consider using the org.springframework.web.reactive.client.WebClient which has a more modern API and supports sync, async, and streaming scenarios

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html

When I am trying to replace RestTemplate with WebClient using Open Api Code generator, I am unable to make Synchronous Calls.

pom.xml code

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${openapi-tool-version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>Games</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                <library>webclient</library>
               <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/spec/games.yaml</inputSpec>
                <configOptions>
                    <configPackage>com.tintin.config</configPackage>
                    <apiPackage>com.tintin.api</apiPackage>
                    <modelPackage>com.tintin.model</modelPackage>
                    <invokerPackage>com.tintin.service</invokerPackage>
                    <sourceFolder>src/main/java</sourceFolder>
                    <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                </configOptions>
                <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

By default webclient is making Asynchronous call and wrapping the responses in Mono<>.

```
public <T> Mono<T> invokeAPI(String path, HttpMethod method, Map<String, Object> pathParams, MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams, Object body, HttpHeaders headerParams, MultiValueMap<String, String> cookieParams, MultiValueMap<String, Object> formParams, List<MediaType> accept, MediaType contentType, String[] authNames, ParameterizedTypeReference<T> returnType) throws RestClientException {
    final WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestBuilder = prepareRequest(path, method, pathParams, queryParams, body, headerParams, cookieParams, formParams, accept, contentType, authNames);
    return requestBuilder.retrieve().bodyToMono(returnType);
}
```

Expected Output (Simillar to resttemplate)

```
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> invokeAPI(String path, HttpMethod method, Map<String, Object> pathParams, MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams, Object body, HttpHeaders headerParams, MultiValueMap<String, String> cookieParams, MultiValueMap<String, Object> formParams, List<MediaType> accept, MediaType contentType, String[] authNames, ParameterizedTypeReference<T> returnType) throws RestClientException {
    final WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestBuilder = prepareRequest(path, method, pathParams, queryParams, body, headerParams, cookieParams, formParams, accept, contentType, authNames);
    return requestBuilder.retrieve().bodyToMono(returnType).block();
}
```

How can I replace Resttemplate with Webclient using open api code generator without making any major changes in my current code

Comment: what version of ${openapi-tool-version} are you using?  Try to update and see if that helps.

Comment: @SMA Updated version to 5.4.0 still response is getting wrapped in Mono and making a Asych call

Comment: I see that you created an enhancement, hope someone makes it customizable.  https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/11678

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting to generate Rest Template classes but you are using `<library>webclient</library>`, please change to `<library>resttemplate</library>` read the whole docs here https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/java/